# Error in Simple Flexbox model

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to align boxes in flexbox model.
here's the code that I used:

```css
<style>

  *{
   margin: 0;
  }

  .wrapper{
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 960px;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .container{
   display: flex;
  }

  .box{
   height: 100px;
   min-width: 100px;
   margin: 20px;
  }

  .one{
   background: purple;
  }

  .two{
   background: yellow;
  }

  .three{
   background: orange;
  }
```

```html
<body>

 
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="box one">I'm Faded</div>
   <div class="box two">I'm Faded</div>
   <div class="box three">I'm Faded</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

If you click on full page, you will see something like this: [image: Output]

I can't figure out why is there white space in front of the purple box, also how can I resolve it ?
please Suggest.

Answer (score 1):

```css
<style>

  *{
   margin: 0;
  }

  .wrapper{
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 960px;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .container{
   display: flex;
  }

  .box{
   height: 100px;
   min-width: 100px;
   /* margin: 20px; 8?
  }

  .one{
   background: purple;
  }

  .two{
   background: yellow;
  }

  .three{
   background: orange;
  }
```

```html
<body>

 
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="box one">I'm Faded</div>
   <div class="box two">I'm Faded</div>
   <div class="box three">I'm Faded</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

You were adding margin in box class, if you remove it, extra space will be removed front every side of coloured boxes (including front)

Answer (score 1):

> If you click on full page, you will see something like this: (white space of purple box's left side)

Yes, and that is caused by the fact that you have set the container to a `max-width` and then center it using `margin: 0 auto`, so on wider screen that is exactly what will happen

*In below sample I added a border on the wrapper so one can see what happens*

```css
<style>* {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dotted red;          /* added to show what's going on */
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.one {
  background: purple;
}

.two {
  background: yellow;
}

.three {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box one">I'm Faded</div>
      <div class="box two">I'm Faded</div>
      <div class="box three">I'm Faded</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

Now based on how you actually want them to align, there are many solution, like this, where they are spread evenly using `justify-content: space-around`

```css
<style>* {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dotted red;           /* added to show what's going on */
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;    /* added to show what's going on */
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.one {
  background: purple;
}

.two {
  background: yellow;
}

.three {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box one">I'm Faded</div>
      <div class="box two">I'm Faded</div>
      <div class="box three">I'm Faded</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

If to remove the left white space completely, just remove the `margin: 0 auto` and `max-width: 960px`

```css
<style>* {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted red;          /* added to show what's going on */
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.one {
  background: purple;
}

.two {
  background: yellow;
}

.three {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box one">I'm Faded</div>
      <div class="box two">I'm Faded</div>
      <div class="box three">I'm Faded</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @h99lb0y When an answer is _spot on_, you are suppose to accept it as well

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:--

```css
  *{
   margin: 0;
  }

  .wrapper{
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 960px;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .container{
   display: flex;
   justify-content:space-between;
  }

  .box{
   height: 100px;
   min-width: 100px;
   
  }

  .one{
   background: purple;
  }

  .two{
   background: yellow;
  
  }

  .three{
   background: orange;
  
  }
```

```html
<body>

 
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="box one">I'm Faded</div>
   <div class="box two">I'm Faded</div>
   <div class="box three">I'm Faded</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**What kind of white space you talking about**,  is it just after the box, so better way is to remove margin you have set in child div

```css
<style>

  *{
   margin: 0;
  }

  .wrapper{
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 960px;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .container{
   display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-start; 
  }

  .box{
   height: 100px;
   min-width: 100px;
   
  }

  .one{
   background: purple;
  }

  .two{
   background: yellow;
  }

  .three{
   background: orange;
  }
```

```html
<body>

 
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="box one">I'm Faded</div>
   <div class="box two">I'm Faded</div>
   <div class="box three">I'm Faded</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```